# How to Send a print job from Hosting server to loacal pc?

Tags: php, localhost

I need help in php printing from printer. I tried some code for printing its working on localhost but after uploading it does not show or perfrom anything. The code i used

```
$getprt=printer_list( PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL );


//echo 'printer list'.json_encode($getprt).'<br />';        

$printer = $getprt[4]['NAME']; 
echo $printer;

if($ph = printer_open($printer))
{
   // Get file contents
   $fh = fopen("filename.txt", "rb");
   $content = fread($fh, filesize("filename.txt"));
   fclose($fh);

   // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer
   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
   printer_write($ph, $content);
   printer_close($ph)
```

it shows the printers on localhost, but when i upload and call this page it does not show or perform anything. 
Actually I want to select print from printer list but for testing I set it manually, This list shows when I run website form localhost but not form hosting server.
Please help me to solve the problem. I'm not experienced about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that PHP runs on the server and not on the client PC. So your code is looking for printers on your hosting package, and there wont be any, and even if there where they would be useless to your site user.

You will need to do this using some javascript in the browser.

With javascript you can get the browser to load the standard print dialog like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.print();
<script>
```

However, this just prints the current page. So you are going to have to re-develop the process so that you throw a web page that looks like the print the user want.

Then at the bottom of the page add the Javascript above and the user should see there own local printers and be able to select the printer and any options from the standard Client print dialog.

Comment: its useful suggestion but with it print preview popup, I want to print directly without print preview

Comment: You cannot print from PHP to the clients machine, you can only throw web pages. It would be insecure to allow a website to do anything like this without the users permission, so this is the only way

Comment: actuly I want to add it in admin panel on click

Comment: its not for end user, its for web admins

Comment: If they are using a web-page/website to do the admin it makes no difference

Comment: You could format the print to lets say a Word Document (for example) and throw that to the browser for them to open Word and do the print themselves. But if the webserver is not on the same local network as the user, PHP just cannot do the printing directly.

Comment: thanks but its client's requirment to print just on click without preview. Client want to print "gif" images

Comment: Well good luck, if you find a solution, please post it here I would love to know how to do it, and so would HP. Think of all the ink they could make you buy if every time you visited there site they threw a 1000 page document at your printer without your permission. But seriously I would like to know if you find a solution.